# SQL Server Group By Order By Where

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, group-by, sql-order-by

I have a single table which I need to pull back the 5 most recent records based on a userID and keying off of documentID (no duplicates).  Basically, I'm tracking visited pages and trying to pull back the 3 most recent by user.

Sample data:

```
╔══════════════════════════════════════════════╗
║UserID   DocumentID   CreatedDate             ║
╠══════════════════════════════════════════════╣
║  71         22       2013-09-09 12:19:37.930 ║
║  71         25       2013-09-09 12:20:37.930 ║
║  72          1       2012-11-09 12:19:37.930 ║
║  99         76       2012-10-10 12:19:37.930 ║
║  71         22       2013-09-09 12:19:37.930 ║
╚══════════════════════════════════════════════╝
```

Desired query results if UserID = 71:

```
╔══════════════════════════════════════════════╗
║UserID    DocumentID  CreatedDate             ║
╠══════════════════════════════════════════════╣
║  71         25       2013-09-09 12:20:37.930 ║
║  71         22       2013-09-09 12:19:37.930 ║
╚══════════════════════════════════════════════╝
```

Comment: Have you tried writing the script yourself?  If so, please post it even if was erroneous.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
SELECT TOP 3 UserId, DocumentId, MAX(CreatedDate)
FROM MyTable
WHERE UserId = 71
GROUP BY UserId, DocumentId
ORDER BY MAX(CreatedDate) DESC
```

Comment: quick question: this would not work in MySQL since it does the ordering after grouping (it would execute without error, but it would produce results that may or may not be 'correct'); can someone confirm that this would work in SQL Server, and is thus a difference between the 2 engines?

Comment: @user2426679 - this did work for me using Sql Server 2016.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using a [CTE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) and [ROW_NUMBER](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx).

Something like

```
;WITH Vals AS (
    SELECT UserID, 
           DocumentID, 
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY UserID, DocumnentID ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC) RowID
    FROM MyTable
)
SELECT TOP 3 *
FROM Vals
WHERE UserID = 71
AND RowID = 1
```

Comment: I don't think that your query returns the required CreatedDate. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT USERID, 
                DOCUMENTID, 
                MAX(CREATEDDATE) 
                  OVER ( 
                    PARTITION BY USERID, DOCUMENTID) CREATEDDATE 
FROM   MYTABLE 
WHERE  USERID = 71
```

Take a look at the working example on [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/30de1/5).

Good Luck!

Answer (score -1):

```
Select USERID,DOCUMENT ID 
FROM yourtable
QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER OVER(Partition by user id ORDER By document id Desc)<6
```

This works in Teradata. Hope this works in Sql Server too as its mainly ANSI SQL.

Comment: I don't think `QUALIFY` is ANSI SQL.

Comment: select USERID,DOCUMENT ID,ROW_NUMBER OVER(Partition by user id ORDER By document id Desc) Rownum FROM yourtable having rownum<6